# How do I locate proper radio initialization procedure in order to send IEEE 802.15.4 frame?

Tags: microcontroller, rf, embedded, msp430, transceiver

I am using an [AT86RF233 radio](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8351-MCU_Wireless-AT86RF233_Datasheet.pdf) connected to an MSP 430 micro-controller.

I need to write a function similar to line 92 on [this page](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/uracoli/file/47941298b3c4/Src/Lib/Rf230/trx_rf230_frame.c).  This function (trx_frame_write) is supposed write a frame for the RF230, not the RF233.  I have copied this function and got it to compile on MSP 430 but it has been unsuccessful in sending frames to a [Digi Xbee Pro Series 1 radio](http://www.digi.com/products/wireless-wired-embedded-solutions/zigbee-rf-modules/point-multipoint-rfmodules/xbee-series1-module#overview).

My hunch is there is nothing wrong with the function itself, but rather the radio's configuration / initialization.

I was hoping one of the experts in the community can point me to the pg. in the data sheet that explains how a radio should be configured so that it can send IEEE 802.15.4 frames correctly.  Section 6.3.2 on pg. 17 definitely jumps out regarding how a frame should be sent, but there is no mention of how the radio itself should be configured.